# Resize partitions Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, dell, gparted

I have a Dell Latitude 5580 and I reduced the factory Windows 10 partition by 15GB. Then I installed Ubuntu on those 15GB.

Now I want to increase the space by 10GB in my Linux. How can I do this safely with GParted live without damaging anything?

My GParted table looks like the attached picture.

[image]
<sup>**GParted live disk listing**</sup>

When I tried to move the unallocated space I got a warning that changing this may alter my bootloader.

This is my current free space in Ubuntu:

[image: IMG:]
<sup>**free space**</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First I would add 20GB not 10GB.

Next use Widows t move the NTFS partitons to the front so the free space is next to the linux partition.
Then, use gparted to grow the Linux partition.

This method allows you add space without actually moving the boot files that grub needs.

Another solution would be to make a new partition with the free space and move your /home folder to the new partition.

Answer (score 0):

**You'll need to have:**

- a Windows install/repair disc
- a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- backups of your important files

**In Windows:**

Use the Windows Disk Management app to move partitions sda4/5/6 toward the front of the disk.

**In the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB:**

---

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

---

- start `gparted`
- **move** sda7 toward the front of the disk
- **resize** the right-side of sda7 all the way to the right
- click the `Accept` icon
- when complete, quit `gparted` and reboot